# Javascript - error handling stopping code

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, discord.js, try-catch

quick basic question,

When setting up [`guildmember.timout`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=timeout) with discord.js v13, it gives an example with `.then(console.log)` and `.catch(console.error)`. Using the example, the code will continue after the .catch.

```js
      muteMember
        .timeout(time, reason)
        .catch((error) => {
          return errors(client, message, args, "mute", error, true);
        });

      muteMember.send ...
```

At the moment it will run the `errors` function then continue onto the code after the `.catch`, for example `muteMember.send`. What's the best way to have it *"stop"* after it runs what is inside of the .catch? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it return a falsy if the error occurs, then check if it is falsy, and return if it is.

```js
let isModified = await muteMember
        .timeout(time, reason)
        .catch((error) => {
            errors(client, message, args, "mute", error, true)
            return false;
        })
if (!isModified) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use async-await with try-catch:

```js
async function myFunction()
{
  try
  {
    await muteMember.timeout(time, reason)
    // throws an error if it fails -- jumps to the catch block

    muteMember.send...
  }
  catch(error)
  {
    errorcheck = true
    errors(client, message, args, "mute", error, true);
    // and whatever other error handling you would like
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement only returns out of the `#catch` callback. Handle the promise with a `#then` callback, thats where you want your code to run when its successful.

```js
muteMember
    .timeout(time, reason)
    .catch((error) => {
        //error
        errorcheck = true
        return errors(client, message, args, "mute", error, true);
    })
    .then(() => {
        //success
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

muteMember.timeout() returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so any code that you want to run after the promise resolves you should wrap in a then() block:

```
muteMember
        .timeout(time, reason)
        .then((member) => {
          // code that depends on successfully timing out a member
          muteMember.send....
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // only runs if there's an error
          errorcheck = true
          return errors(client, message, args, "mute", error, true);
        });
```

You can also use the more modern and readable [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax:

```
const myAsyncFunction = async () => {
  try {
    const member = await muteMember.timeout(time, reason);
    // code that depends on successfully timing out a member
    muteMember.send....
  } catch (error) {  
    // only runs if there's an error
    errorcheck = true
    return errors(client, message, args, "mute", error, true);
  }
}
```